# Spring 3 Request Handlers: When to return a value, when not, when to redirect?

Tags: java, forms, spring, return, illegalstateexception

I'm learning Spring.  I've written a few Controller classes so far and a number of RequestHandler methods in those controllers.   I don't think I fully understand some of the examples I based my code on, as I seem to get IllegalStateExceptions inexplicably.

I've noticed in Googling around at some examples of RequestHandlers,

```
some return a String so that the DispatcherServlet can route it to a view ( JSP )
some return a String as above, but with a "redirect:" or "forward:" prefix
some just return a Model object
```

My intuition is that my lack of understanding for what to return and when and why is behind my IllegalStateExceptions.

If a RequestHandler is sending data to a view (jsp) should the "redirect:" prefix be used in the return statement?  Yes? No?  Why?  Why Not?

If this is explained in corner of the massive documentation that I missed please feel free to RTFM me with a URL

Thanks

Comment: Post the handler method from where you return `"redirect:*"` to take it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **redirect:** and **forward:** works just like we do simple **requestDispatcher.sendRedirect** and **requestDispatcher.forward** in jsp-servlet.

Spring has just provided better way to do the same thing with just prefixing the *redirect* or *forward* keyword to your string.

For further undestanding please refer the following url.

[Reference for Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/mvc.html)

and refer to topic no. **13.5.3.2.** and **13.5.3.3.**

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.